# как преобразовать вложенный массив js в объект js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
[Array(0), Array(0)] 
0: [id: "2", print: "1", inspection: "Color", method: "ASTM D1500", result: "55"] 
1: [id: "3", print: "1", inspection: "Color2", method: "ASTM D15002", result: "36"]
```

преобразовать в

{
{"id": "2", "print": "1", "inspection": "Color", "method": "ASTM D1500", "result": "55"}
{"id": "3", "print": "1", "inspection": "Color2", "method": "ASTM D15002", "result": "36"}
}

Comment: не надо один и тот же вопрос задавать несколько раз